# how should I run android in a linux container (lxc)?

Tags: android, linux, virtualization, lxc

I'd like to test android apps on my system without a slow emulator.

Is it possible to run android in another linux host, like gentoo or ubuntu?
How would one acomplish this, maybe trough docker?
In case of gentoo, are there specific kernel modules I need to enable?

Comment: Are you coding on ARM system? If no - there is no way to use LXC.

Comment: @BaBL86 No but there is a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android-x86 

I see youre point, it will be impossible to virtaulize arm this way. However most android aps are writen in a form of java, which should comply to wora: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once,_run_anywhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu Touch runs Android inside a container. You can run Arm Android on x86, see here:

https://www.stgraber.org/2013/12/23/lxc-1-0-some-more-advanced-container-usage/

and here:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/ContainerArchitecture

It should be possible to run x86 Android natively inside a container. At the end of the day Android also runs on x86 devices such as the Nexus Player.